# Why use $(this) not $(value)?

Tags: jquery

I'm looking at some jQuery code

```
$items.each(function (index, value) {
    $(this).hover(function () { /* blah ... */ });
});
```

It seems to be idiomatic jQuery to use `$(this)` rather than `$(value)` though they are identical. Why? Surely the latter is more obvious and thus better?

Comment: i think youll get error if you use `$(value)` because i think `value` = `$(this).val()`.

Comment: wrapping the DOMElement in jQuery object again, why when you have tHiS

Comment: That's just code style (btw using `value` make it less readable than e.g `item`). That's said, here the `each` loop is useless anyway because `hover()` method works on collection

Comment: @MLM No it refers to [iterated element](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev This sin't duplicate, here OP is using `$.fn.each` not `$.each`

Comment: @A.Wolff As fas as I know, `$obj.each(...)` simply calls `$.each($obj, ...)`.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev That's true but could be confusing to dupe question with different method